# access to RESTful API in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, laravel, api

I have laravel in server side, that can show api with entering this url: `http://localhost:8000/api/cabangs`, and show this (the data as example):

```
[
 {
  "id":2,
  "nm_cabang":"zxcvb",
  "deskripsi":"poiuyt",
  "created_at":"2020-08-08T05:25:31.000000Z",
  "updated_at":"2020-08-08T05:29:23.000000Z"
 },
 {
  "id":3,
  "nm_cabang":"asdfg",
  "deskripsi":"qwerty",
  "created_at":"2020-08-08T05:28:26.000000Z",
  "updated_at":"2020-08-08T05:28:26.000000Z"
 }
]
```

I want to only display `nm_cabang` and `deskripsi`. if it's possible, using `react hooks`. thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please post some code demonstrating your goal so that we can help further debug any specific problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with something like this.
I'm assuming this is for the web so I used `span` and `div`.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState();
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/cabangs');
        if (result.ok)
        {
            let json = await result.json();
            setData(json);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        //error
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <span>Loading...</span>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {
      data ? (
        data.map((item) => {
          return <span>{`${item.nm_cabang} ${item.deskripsi}`}</span>;
        })
      ) : (
        <></>
      )
      }
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Maybe this can look hard to understand if it's your first time connecting your front to an api @Febry Aryo. But it is simple, when you make a request using axios or fetch, the method returns an objecti whit info about the request, for example its status code, the data from the api and the headers of the response, and you can make anything you want whit that information.

Comment: this question is solved. I used axios as alternative. thanks for all answers :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a library like axios or fetch, you only need to make the http request to the url and use the data you need.

https://github.com/axios/axios
https://javascript.info/fetch

I like axios